# Postfix / Dovecot not receiving e-mails in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, dovecot

I've just setup a VPS with Ubuntu 14.04 at Linode. I have installed Postfix, Dovecot & SquirrelMail to handle E-mail. I am able to send e-mails to other accounts (GMail & Yahoo!) but when I send an e-mail to my self, it's not getting delivered into my inbox.

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/server.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = n3rve.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = n3rve.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
virtual_alias_domains = 
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
inet_protocols = ipv4
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_transport = dovecot
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
owner_request_special = no
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth

content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
message_size_limit = 0
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
```

/var/log/mail.log

```
Jan 29 11:03:28 n3rve amavis[2421]: starting. /usr/sbin/amavisd-new at n3rve.com amavisd-new-2.7.1 (20120429), Unicode aware
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Net::Server: Group Not Defined.  Defaulting to EGID '119 119'
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Net::Server: User Not Defined.  Defaulting to EUID '110'
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Amavis::Conf        2.303
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Archive::Zip        1.30
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module BerkeleyDB          0.54
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Compress::Zlib      2.06
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Convert::TNEF       0.18
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Convert::UUlib      1.4
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA 0.28
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module DBD::mysql          4.025
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module DBI                 1.63
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module DB_File             1.827
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Digest::MD5         2.52
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Digest::SHA         5.84_01
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module File::Temp          0.23
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module IO::Socket::INET6   2.71
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module MIME::Entity        5.505
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module MIME::Parser        5.505
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module MIME::Tools         5.505
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Mail::DKIM::Signer  0.4
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Mail::DKIM::Verifier 0.4
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Mail::Header        2.12
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Mail::Internet      2.12
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Mail::SPF           v2.009
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Mail::SpamAssassin  3.004000
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Net::DNS            0.68
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Net::Server         2.007
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module NetAddr::IP         4.071
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Socket6             0.25
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Time::HiRes         1.9725
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module URI                 1.60
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Module Unix::Syslog        1.1
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Amavis::DB code      loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: SQL base code        loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: SQL::Log code        NOT loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: SQL::Quarantine      NOT loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Lookup::SQL code     loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Lookup::LDAP code    NOT loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: AM.PDP-in proto code loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: SMTP-in proto code   loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Courier proto code   NOT loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: SMTP-out proto code  loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Pipe-out proto code  NOT loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: BSMTP-out proto code NOT loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Local-out proto code loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: OS_Fingerprint code  NOT loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: ANTI-VIRUS code      loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: ANTI-SPAM code       loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: ANTI-SPAM-EXT code   NOT loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: ANTI-SPAM-C code     NOT loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: ANTI-SPAM-SA code    loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Unpackers code       loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: DKIM code            loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Tools code           NOT loaded
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found $file            at /usr/bin/file
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: No $altermime,         not using it
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Internal decoder for .mail
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: No decoder for       .F   
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found decoder for    .Z    at /bin/uncompress
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Internal decoder for .gz  
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found decoder for    .bz2  at /bin/bzip2 -d
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found decoder for    .xz   at /usr/bin/xz -dc
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found decoder for    .lzma at /usr/bin/xz -dc --format=lzma
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found decoder for    .lzo  at /usr/bin/lzop -d
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: No decoder for       .rpm  tried: rpm2cpio.pl, rpm2cpio
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found decoder for    .cpio at /bin/pax
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found decoder for    .tar  at /bin/pax
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found decoder for    .deb  at /usr/bin/ar
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Internal decoder for .zip 
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Internal decoder for .kmz 
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: No decoder for       .7z   tried: 7zr, 7za, 7z
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: No decoder for       .rar  tried: unrar-free
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found decoder for    .arj  at /usr/bin/arj
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found decoder for    .arc  at /usr/bin/nomarch
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found decoder for    .zoo  at /usr/bin/zoo
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: No decoder for       .doc  tried: ripole
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found decoder for    .cab  at /usr/bin/cabextract
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: No decoder for       .tnef
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Internal decoder for .tnef
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found decoder for    .exe  at /usr/bin/arj
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Using primary internal av scanner code for ClamAV-clamd
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Found secondary av scanner ClamAV-clamscan at /usr/bin/clamscan
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Deleting db files __db.002,__db.003,snmp.db,nanny.db,__db.001 in /var/lib/amavis/db
Jan 29 11:03:29 n3rve amavis[2872]: Creating db in /var/lib/amavis/db/; BerkeleyDB 0.54, libdb 5.3
Jan 29 11:03:37 n3rve dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.9 starting up (core dumps disabled)
Jan 29 11:03:40 n3rve postfix/master[3779]: daemon started -- version 2.11.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Jan 29 11:05:01 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (disconnected before auth was ready, waited 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<vKmkdcgNaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:05:01 n3rve dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<p2SldcgNEgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:05:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4173]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:05:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4173]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:05:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4173]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:10:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4322]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:10:01 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (disconnected before auth was ready, waited 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<O1N9h8gNeQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:10:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4322]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:10:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4322]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:10:01 n3rve dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<84R9h8gNIwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:15:01 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (disconnected before auth was ready, waited 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<lAhfmcgNhAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:15:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4524]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:15:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4524]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:15:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4524]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:15:01 n3rve dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<73ZfmcgNLgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:17:46 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=41.203.69.46, lip=45.56.99.63, mpid=4581, TLS, session=<Ymk2o8gN8wApy0Uu>
Jan 29 11:20:01 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (disconnected before auth was ready, waited 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<UFZBq8gNkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:20:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4627]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:20:01 n3rve dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<m8BBq8gNOgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:20:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4627]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:20:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4627]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:25:01 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (disconnected before auth was ready, waited 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<rzkjvcgNmQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:25:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4715]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:25:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4715]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:25:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4715]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:25:01 n3rve dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<154jvcgNQwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:28:53 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=4773, secured, session=<1xn1ysgNngAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:28:53 n3rve dovecot: imap(n3rve@n3rve.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=44 out=843
Jan 29 11:28:54 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=4775, secured, session=<IO8By8gNnwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:28:54 n3rve dovecot: imap(n3rve@n3rve.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=261 out=1691
Jan 29 11:28:54 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=4777, secured, session=<hOsDy8gNoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:28:54 n3rve dovecot: imap(n3rve@n3rve.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=117 out=1508
Jan 29 11:29:27 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4786]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:29:27 n3rve postfix/trivial-rewrite[4788]: warning: do not list domain n3rve.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Jan 29 11:29:27 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4786]: B6DCB1204D: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:29:27 n3rve postfix/cleanup[4795]: B6DCB1204D: message-id=<41bfb9423f652535329ba1510d7c2140.squirrel@n3rve.com>
Jan 29 11:29:27 n3rve postfix/qmgr[3786]: B6DCB1204D: from=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, size=684, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 29 11:29:27 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4786]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:29:27 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=4798, secured, session=<OL0EzcgNqgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:29:27 n3rve dovecot: imap(n3rve@n3rve.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=587 out=525
Jan 29 11:29:28 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4803]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:29:28 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4803]: 541B11204E: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:29:28 n3rve postfix/cleanup[4795]: 541B11204E: message-id=<41bfb9423f652535329ba1510d7c2140.squirrel@n3rve.com>
Jan 29 11:29:28 n3rve postfix/qmgr[3786]: 541B11204E: from=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, size=1094, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan 29 11:29:28 n3rve amavis[3429]: (03429-01) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInternal}, LOCAL [127.0.0.1]:54362 [41.203.69.46] <n3rve@n3rve.com> -> <n3rve@n3rve.com>, Queue-ID: B6DCB1204D, Message-ID: <41bfb9423f652535329ba1510d7c2140.squirrel@n3rve.com>, mail_id: ljoCyR3XiMNg, Hits: 1.439, size: 684, queued_as: 541B11204E, 530 ms
Jan 29 11:29:28 n3rve postfix/smtp[4796]: B6DCB1204D: to=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=0.63, delays=0.05/0.02/0.05/0.5, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 541B11204E)
Jan 29 11:29:28 n3rve postfix/qmgr[3786]: B6DCB1204D: removed
Jan 29 11:29:28 n3rve postfix/local[4804]: 541B11204E: to=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0/0.02/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jan 29 11:29:28 n3rve postfix/qmgr[3786]: 541B11204E: removed
Jan 29 11:29:28 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=4806, secured, session=<Z1kVzcgNrgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:29:28 n3rve dovecot: imap(n3rve@n3rve.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=117 out=1508
Jan 29 11:30:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4786]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:30:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4786]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:30:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4786]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:30:01 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<dT0Fz8gNtQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:30:01 n3rve dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<C0MFz8gNXwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4786]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4786]: A284F1204D: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/cleanup[4866]: A284F1204D: message-id=<215f06b32157d93268f01c8769924b56.squirrel@n3rve.com>
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/qmgr[3786]: A284F1204D: from=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, size=746, nrcpt=3 (queue active)
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4786]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=4873, secured, session=<Ml5k08gNwgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve dovecot: imap(n3rve@n3rve.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=698 out=525
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4878]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/trivial-rewrite[4868]: warning: do not list domain n3rve.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4878]: E5FA41204E: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/cleanup[4866]: E5FA41204E: message-id=<215f06b32157d93268f01c8769924b56.squirrel@n3rve.com>
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/qmgr[3786]: E5FA41204E: from=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, size=1110, nrcpt=3 (queue active)
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve amavis[3440]: (03440-01) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInternal,RelayedOutbound}, LOCAL [127.0.0.1]:54385 [41.203.69.46] <n3rve@n3rve.com> -> <ralphotowo@gmail.com>,<n3rve@n3rve.com>,<ralphotowo@yahoo.com>, Queue-ID: A284F1204D, Message-ID: <215f06b32157d93268f01c8769924b56.squirrel@n3rve.com>, mail_id: qwTrh-5H0qYf, Hits: 1.438, size: 746, queued_as: E5FA41204E, 214 ms
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/smtp[4870]: A284F1204D: to=<ralphotowo@gmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=0.32, delays=0.07/0.03/0.01/0.21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E5FA41204E)
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/smtp[4870]: A284F1204D: to=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=0.32, delays=0.07/0.03/0.01/0.21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E5FA41204E)
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/smtp[4870]: A284F1204D: to=<ralphotowo@yahoo.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=0.32, delays=0.07/0.03/0.01/0.21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as E5FA41204E)
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/qmgr[3786]: A284F1204D: removed
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/local[4882]: E5FA41204E: to=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.01/0.02/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jan 29 11:31:15 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=4885, secured, session=</Zpr08gNyQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:31:15 n3rve dovecot: imap(n3rve@n3rve.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=117 out=1508
Jan 29 11:31:15 n3rve postfix/smtp[4883]: E5FA41204E: to=<ralphotowo@yahoo.com>, relay=mta7.am0.yahoodns.net[66.196.118.35]:25, delay=0.59, delays=0.01/0.04/0.1/0.44, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok dirdel)
Jan 29 11:31:15 n3rve postfix/smtp[4881]: E5FA41204E: to=<ralphotowo@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.29.27]:25, delay=0.84, delays=0.01/0.03/0.21/0.58, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1422531075 1si9841245qam.65 - gsmtp)
Jan 29 11:31:15 n3rve postfix/qmgr[3786]: E5FA41204E: removed
Jan 29 11:31:17 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=4887, secured, session=<O0iV08gNygAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:31:17 n3rve dovecot: imap(n3rve@n3rve.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=293 out=5997
Jan 29 11:31:20 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=4889, secured, session=<hwK108gNywAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:31:20 n3rve dovecot: imap(n3rve@n3rve.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=145 out=1676
Jan 29 11:31:22 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=4891, secured, session=<NurX08gNzAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:31:22 n3rve dovecot: imap(n3rve@n3rve.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=117 out=1508
Jan 29 11:34:28 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4803]: timeout after END-OF-MESSAGE from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:34:28 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4803]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:35:01 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<ygXn4MgN2AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:35:01 n3rve dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<Hwzn4MgNggAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:35:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4949]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:35:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4949]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:35:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4949]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:36:14 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4878]: timeout after END-OF-MESSAGE from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:36:14 n3rve postfix/smtpd[4878]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:38:55 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=::1, lip=::1, mpid=4999, secured, session=<asnb7sgN2wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:38:55 n3rve dovecot: imap(n3rve@n3rve.com): Disconnected: Logged out in=79 out=777
Jan 29 11:40:01 n3rve dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (disconnected before auth was ready, waited 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<s+zM8sgN5wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:40:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[5056]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:40:01 n3rve dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=::1, lip=::1, secured, session=<8mnN8sgNkQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB>
Jan 29 11:40:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[5056]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jan 29 11:40:01 n3rve postfix/smtpd[5056]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

What am I doing wrong, how can I fix it?

Comment: What's error did you get when sending email? Did you set mx record properly? Also please check the content of /var/log/mail.log

Comment: @masegaloeh No error at all. I've attached the log file here. I have no problem sending to other accounts. I can't receive mails on the server.

Comment: Remove n3rve.com from mydestination parameter

Comment: @masegaloeh I did as you said and everything is working as expected. Will you consider posting that as an answer and explaining why that was an issue so I can mark it as an accepted solution, and hopefully help some other frustrated fellow. Thanks? :)

Comment: @masegaloeh And if you won't mind clearing something up for me: This is actually a migration from Ubuntu 12.04 to Ubuntu 14.04, I went to check the 'main.cf' file for the former and noticed that the $mydestination parameter contains research.n3rve.com as well as localhost & localhost.domain - Why wasn't this an issue then?

Comment: `warning: do not list domain n3rve.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains`, I don't see an incoming mail in the log.

Comment: I hope answer below addresses your concern, why old server was working fine and the new one wasn't. It because they have different `mydestination` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix has neat official documentation about postfix and its behavior. So it would be good idea to visit postfix [DEBUG README page](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html). In that page. the first step to look sign of trouble is look into `/var/log/maillog` file. When Postfix does not receive or deliver mail, please look for errors that prevent Postfix from working properly by issuing command

```
egrep '(warning|error|fatal|panic):' /var/log/maillog | more
```

In your case, above command will yield result

```
Jan 29 11:29:27 n3rve postfix/trivial-rewrite[4788]: warning: do not list domain n3rve.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
```

To answer why postfix throws above error, you need to understand postfix concept about [address classes](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html). In short, any domain would be member of exactly one address class. That's why postfix complain about domain `n3rve.com` that become member of two address classes. Because of this, postfix think that `n3rve.com` was local domain class and deliver it via `local`.

```
Jan 29 11:31:14 n3rve postfix/local[4882]: E5FA41204E: to=<n3rve@n3rve.com>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.01/0.02/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
```

**The solution was remove `n3rve.com` from either `mydestination` or `virtual_mailbox_domains`.**

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's working perfectly now. While I don't understand your answer given the complexity, I will take out time to go over it in detail. Thanks again!